# 301 Redirect on nginx machine running non-standard port behind a proxy

Tags: redirect, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx server processing PHP requests, but it's configured to listen on a non-standard port (port 12345 or something). I can't change the listen port because corporate IT says, "No."

There is a proxy in the data center that forwards requests from www.domain.com:80 to the nginx box on port 12345.

I have some static 301 redirects that I need to put in place, but I'm getting unexpected behavior.

Sample redirects in site.conf "server { }" block:

```
rewrite ^/foo$ /bar/foo/ permanent;
```

When I attempt to go to www.domain.com/foo, the redirect happens, but it tries to forward the browser to www.domain.com:12345/bar/foo/

My question is, how can I get nginx to redirect the user to the correct port (www.domain.com/bar/foo/)?

Maybe a better question is, what is the correct way to do what I'm asking? There are 50+ redirects that need to go in, and I'd rather not create a "location" section for each of those redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a more explicit rewrite.  Try the following:

```
rewrite ^/foo/ $scheme://www.domain.com:80/bar$request_uri permanent;
```

I have assumed that you meant to use `^/foo/` instead of `^/foo$`, since `^/foo$` is a very specific case.  Just revise as needed.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I really did mean ^/foo/ because it's a specific url I'm targeting (per marketing request). It works great, and I modified it a little:

rewrite ^/foo/ $scheme://$server_name:80/bar/ permanent;